# How to get the whereused list for component template, schemas, page templates either using C# TBB or through sql query on content manager database?

Tags: 2011-sp1

How to get the where used list for component template, schemas, page templates either using C# TBB or through sql query on content manager database in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1? Using Tridion core service is not an option as on our SDL Tridion CMS server core service is not functional.

Comment: You could, of course, take action to get the core service to be functional. What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the 2011 TOM.NET API reference from the Downloads=>Documentation menu on [SDL Tridion World](https://www.sdltridionworld.com/) (login required)

You can definitely get a where used collection or Xml using a C# TBB.

Code examples on [Coded Weapon](http://codedweapon.com/2012/11/getting-using-and-used-items-with-tom-net/)

You can google "Tridion GetUsingItems" to find more examples.

Comment: You're welcome. Sample code and examples are definitely needed to get comfortable with the Where Used functionality. I often get confused (even though it is actually logical) by the fact that GetUsingItems gets you the "Used In" tab if you look at the UI and GetUsedItems gets you the  "Uses" tab. But that's also clarified in Alex's blog article.